# infraestrutura servidor sistema web em php

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor

preciso de uma ajuda com respeito a infraestrutura de servidor web que montei no escritorio da empresa, vamos lá. O sistema foi desenvolvido em php, instalei o linux slackware 14, apache 2.4, php 5.6 e mysql 5.7, contratei a internet de 60 megas de download e 6 de upload da net, fiz o redirecionamento de porta, pois a net bloqueia a porta 80 de planos pessoa fisica. O computador é um core 2 duo com 3 gigas de memoria. A questão é: o sistema acessado de fora fica lento para carregar algumas paginas, as que tem poucos dados carrega rápido, as outras demoram. Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para melhorar a performance do sistema.

Comment: Criem vergonha na cara e hospedem o sistema em um ambiente apropriado. Sai mais barato e fica mais fácil de configurar e manter do que da forma como vocês fizeram, além de não precisar de gambiarra por conta de bloqueio de porta.

Comment: 1) Minify css e JS. 2) Diminua o tamanho das imagens para o menor possivel e também se possivel juntar elas em uma imagem unica e utilizar o css para carregar o que precisa. 3) Tem módulos de compressão de dados para apache, que compacta o dados que são transmitidos. Ajuda bastante.